# How to serve data from GeoServer on remote computer (server)?

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite, web

I have developed an application using GeoExt + OpenLayers + GeoServer and it works fine. I have installed OpenGeo Suite in one of the computers at work (to serve as server) and I have uploaded my application online (cpanel).

The application runs well online but layers do not show because I am unable to connect to my server machine. I have tried to search for online resources but am rather confused on this issue.

I need help on this. Could someone guide me on how am supposed to set my server machine so that it can be accessible online so that layers and popups for my application can work?

Comment: you need to set up your network, so that your GeoServer is accessible from your remote computer. For this,  your server with Geoserver, should be exposed to the internet

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe am trying to do that to no avail.I think is the barrier in this case.Am even confused.Am trying to use the address at "what is my IP" but its not connecting

Comment: That will usualy not work, since it is possible that your ISP or Network or Firewall might prevent incoming connections on the required ports on the external IP of your server. Secondly your internal network configuration would need to be modified to route these incoming requests to the particular server

Comment: I have seen an example of such a thing that I want at http://jsfiddle.net/Alophind/9r95T/ .Maybe @Alophind can help??

Comment: This is an network issue, and only someone who has knowledge of your network can answer it.

Comment: Ok.Thank you alot.I will need to contact the network admin for this.oh discouraging though

Comment: you can set up your router so as to forward your geoserver  through a dyndns address. An Address that your application then can see.